# mysql search where column match with given input or given input with price between given price and price

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I start making code my input  total 7 input field 4 checkbox and 4 input text fields
when i make this its work fine but look something like this search data in mysql where match input 1 or input 2 match between variable1 and variable2 where size between size1 and size2

```
   $fetch=mysql_query("select * from diamonds where diamond-color='".$red."' or diamond-color_pink='".$pink."'  and diamond_price between '".$min_price."' and '".$max_price."'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from diamonds 
 where diamond_price between 1000 and 10000
   and (diamond-color ='red' or diamond-color_pink='pink')
```

Replace with variables where corresponding.

Comment: oh its work great but its work when i use price. and i want to do this if only select color then give all color which match and then i type price then search match color between price and i have 5 more fields witch i use in between

Comment: i am using ur method with some change but u help me in real thank you :))